# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

while trying to process some user input which contains characters such as <.

I do want to sanitize this input and allow it to be displayed and be XSS safe.

I'm getting this ajax error even though I haven't reached the the vb code behind to clean up the input.

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

The input is controlled by a btnNoteSave which is a updatepanel trigger.

```
                <div style="width: 100%; float: left">
                <div>
                    <asp:Button ValidationGroup="valgroup1" ID="btnNoteSave" runat="server" Text="Save"
                        class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all float-left ui-button" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 100%; float: left">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlNotes" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div id="content_container" style="margin-top: 85px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNotes" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNoteSave" EventName="click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

I've tried sanitizing my input in the code behind but I'm not even reaching that far. The error is an ajax error that throws when it reaches here.

```
Protected Sub btnNoteSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNoteSave.Click

....

        newnote.Note = Server.HtmlEncode(txtNote.Text)
 ....

End Sub
```

Any ideas how to get deal with these issues?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add `ValidateRequest="false"` to the @Page directive of your page (or to the `<pages>` element in your web.config file. This disables XSS checking by ASP.NET that is triggered when it encountered < > characters.

If you are still getting 500 errors from the PageRequestManager try temporarily moving the controls outside of the UpdatePanel so you can better inspect the runtime error.